# What is light orange in the minimap about?

Tags: path-of-exile

[image: Light orange area in the minimap]

I'm standing on an area marked in light orange in the minimap in Lower Submerged Passage. There's nothing seems particularly exciting in this location. What's it about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dark orange on the map denotes the entrance/exit to another floor, light orange shows either a doorway, or bridge in the dungeon. I find they tend to help me find my way around much easier as I can keep an eye out for the next area I'm supposed to be going using them as markers.

Answer (score 0):

It just notes the archway on the map you are standing near.